# How to set custom colors in ggplot2 using theme_classic function

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors

I am making a ggplot that shows the probability (from 0 to 1) of 10 species occurring in relation to the percentage of a variable ¨x¨ (6.15% to 99.22%).

I am using the function ggplot and the arguments geom_line and theme_classic (code bellow) and I am happy with the plot overall because I can manually change from a standardized values to the real values as the breaks and labels (sorry if the code is too messy), but the colours for each species are too similar, they get easily confused.

Is there a way to manually select them while using theme_classic?
Is there a simple hack/way to change the colors to others more distinct?

Plot: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/k5st4.jpg

Thanks!

```
ggplot(data=data.table,
   aes(x=percentage.x, y=probability, colour=Species)) + 
geom_line()+ 
theme_classic() + 
xlab("Percentage") + ylab(expression("Probab[enter image description here][1]ility")) +
scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0,1), breaks = seq(0,1, by=.25)) +
scale_x_continuous(
breaks = c( -6.83305, -5.04805, -3.263056, -1.47805, 0.306943954),
label = c(sprintf("%0.2f",((-6.83305*
(realvalue$standard.deviation))+realvalue$average)*100),
          sprintf("%0.2f",((-5.04805*
(realvalue$standard.deviation))+realvalue$average)*100),
          sprintf("%0.2f",((-3.263056*
(realvalue$standard.deviation))+realvalue$average)*100),
          sprintf("%0.2f",((-1.47805*(realvalue$standard.deviation))+realvalue$average)*100),
          sprintf("%0.2f",((0.306943954*(noestandar$desviacion.porcentaje.selva))+noestandar$media.porcentaje.selva)*100)))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or something like:

```
   + scale_colour_manual(values = c("black","blue"))
```

Comment: Thank you! This works perfectly as an argument to: 
geom_line()+ 
  theme_classic() +

Answer (score 1):

I think this will work:

```
... +
scale_colour_brewer(palette = "Set3")
```

ColorBrewer palette "Set3" is a distinct set of more than 10 colors. "Paired" might look good too.

https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/ggplot2/versions/3.3.3/topics/scale_colour_brewer

[image]

Comment: Thanks! This worked as well as as an argument to: 
geom_line()+ 
  theme_classic() +